# redux how to mock useselector

Tags: reactjs, redux, jestjs

In my component

```
const { fileErrors, fileMetaDataId, filePurpose } = useSelector((state) => state.files);
const isFile = filePurpose == 'R';
const displayMessage = isFile ? 'test': 'not testing';
```

in my test

```
import store from '../redux/store';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom';
import { UploadErrors } from '../pages';

test('The error message should be present', async () => {
render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Router>
      <UploadErrors />
    </Router>
  </Provider>
);
expect(screen.getByText('test')).toBeInTheDocument();
});
```

how do I mock filepurpose so that i can test displayMessage

Answer (score 0):

You can mock `useSelector` with `jest.mock()` before running your test suite

**UPDATED CODE**

```js
import store from "../redux/store";
import { Provider, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom";
import { UploadErrors } from "../pages";

jest.mock("react-redux", () => {
  return {
    ...jest.requireActual("react-redux"),
    useSelector: jest.fn(),
  };
});

const mockState = {
  // Your values here
  fileErrors: "",
  fileMetaDataId: "",
  filePurpose: "",
};
beforeAll(() => {
  useSelector.mockImplementation((callback) => {
    return callback(mockState);
  });
});
afterAll(() => {
  useSelector.mockClear();
});
test("The error message should be present", async () => {
  render(
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Router>
        <UploadErrors />
      </Router>
    </Provider>
  );
  expect(screen.getByText("test")).toBeInTheDocument();
});
```

Comment: I tired below but it didnt work, it still assumes filepurpose as empty describe('test', () => {
    jest.mock("react-redux", () => {
        return {
          ...jest.requireActual("react-redux"),
          useSelector: () => {
            return {              
              filePurpose: 'R'
            };
          },
        };
      });
  test('error message', async () => {
    render(
      <Provider store={store}>
        <Router>
          <UploadErrors />
        </Router>
      </Provider>
    );
    expect(screen.getByText('test')).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
});

Comment: where is this render method coming from? what library are you using for testing?